# Python multiprocessing Pool returns same output in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing, spyder, pool

I am using multiprocessing.Pool in Python 3.6, through Spyder 3.6.5 on a Windows 10 machine. The aim is to get the outputs from a simple squared function by importing multiple inputs (in this example only 4 values are included for practical issues). The below code works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

from multiprocessing import Pool

data=[]
data.append(np.array([1,2]))
data.append(np.array([4,5]))

Output=np.zeros((2,2))


for i in range (0,2):

    data1=data[i]

    def square(x):
        return x*x

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        __spec__ = "ModuleSpec(name='builtins', loader=<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>)"
        with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as p:
            output = p.map(square, data1, chunksize=10)
            p.close()
            output=np.asarray(output)
            Output[i]=output
```

while in case when I want to specify input square function values (x) as:

```
def square(ii):
    x=data1[ii]
    return x*x
```

the for loop runs two times (due to 'for i in range (0,2)') but the results of p.map are the same in every run and equal to the second run, i.e. instead of being Output=np.array([[1,4],[16,25]]) I am getting Output=np.array([[16,25],[16,25]]). It seems as the for loop runs two times with i=1 and not as in the first loop i=0 and in the second i=1.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: No time atm to look in detail, but 2 comments: 1. It's weird to place `if __name__ == '__main__':` inside a for loop. Same for the `with Pool()`. First one is checking if the program is not imported, thus it should be at the indent 0. Second one if spawning a Pool of workers. This is a "long" operation, thus it's more efficient to place the `for` loops inside the `with` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Closures in python don't copy values of variables they close over. They just keep a reference to that scope. In your second try, the `square` function is accessing `data1` as if it was different value in both iterations, but it is in fact a reference to the same underlying variable. By the time the multiprocessing module fires up a new process and calls `square`, the variable has already changed.

Try this for instance:

```
res = []
for i in range(5):
    def square():
        return i * i
    res.append(square)


print([f() for f in res])
```

As for a solution you could manually create a new scope with the appropriate value in each iteration.

A function call creates a new scope, so you could define a helper function like this outside the loop

```
def square_creater(data1):
    def square(ii):
        x = data1[ii]
        return x * x
    return square
```

and then at each iteration use

```
square = square_creater(data1)
```

This should work.

Comment: Dear merlyn thank you for your instant response. I see with your example the closures issue in python. Attempting to alter the code by following your guidance I get the error "Can't pickle local object 'square_creater.<locals>.square'" in row "output = p.map(square, range(2), chunksize=10)". You can see the new code version

Comment: def square_creater(data1):
    def square(ii):
        x = data1[ii]
        return x * x
    return square

for i in range (0,2):
    
    data1=data[i]
    
    square = square_creater(data1)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        __spec__ = "ModuleSpec(name='builtins', loader=<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>)"
        with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as p:
            output = p.map(square, range(2), chunksize=10)
            p.close()
            output=np.asarray(output)
            Output[i]=output

Comment: @GeorgeKouskoulis I just tried your new code with the original square definition and I am getting the expected [[1., 4.], [16., 25.]]. Do you have a full source for the file that returns [[16, 25], [16, 25]]?

Comment: Code that returns [[16,25],[16,25]] is:`data=[]
data.append(np.array([1,2]))
data.append(np.array([4,5]))
Output=np.zeros((2,2))
for i in range (0,2):
    data1=data[i]
    def square(ii):
        x=data1[ii]
        return x*x
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        __spec__ = "ModuleSpec(name='builtins', loader=<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>)"
        with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as p:
            output = p.map(square, range(2), chunksize=10)
            p.close()
            p.join()
            output=np.asarray(output)
            Output[i]=output`

Comment: @GeorgeKouskoulis Again, I am getting [[1, 4], [16, 25]], both on my own machine as well as [online](https://www.jdoodle.com/python3-programming-online)

Comment: You are right! On python online results are [[1, 4], [16, 25]]! Though on Spyder and Python IDLE are [[16, 25], [16, 25]].